# Dynamic Rows in a Table

Tags: itemize, enumitem

I would to setup a command in LaTeX that would allow me to pass in multiple arguments (like a list) that would populate a table. As far I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a way of doing it. Here is what I have so far.

```
\UsePackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\speciallist}[6]{
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3.5cm,labelsep=0.5cm]
    \item[\textsc{#1:}] #2
    \item[\textsc{#3:}] #4
    \item[\textsc{#5:}] #6
\end{itemize}
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to pass multiple `\item` entries to the itemize table. Maybe in one scenario I pass in 8 arguments, so it gives me 4 entries. In another I pass only 2 so I get a single entry. I hope that makes sense. Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `\UsePackage`? ;-)

Comment: I see no table here, do you intend only a list?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: It looks like a table... in fact it is a table, but not in the sense of `tabular` etc.

Comment: The `\textsc{...}` settings can be applied with the general option `font=\scshape`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Hence could the result be reached also with `csvreader` or `pgfplotstable`, for example?

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Yes, of course. Go ahead with solutions based on the mentioned packages... In fact, David would say that such lists should be done with a tabular anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way with `expl3` (loaded by `xparse`), applying a comma separated value list and looping over it with `\int_step_inline:nnnn`, in steps of two.

If the list is empty, nothing is printed or if number of items is not dividable by two, there is no harm. `\seq_item:Nn` does return in this case if the 2nd argument points beyond the list.

The first optional argument is meant for `enumitem` settings.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\speciallist}{O{}+m}{%
  \group_begin:
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_tmpa_seq {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3.5cm,labelsep=0.5cm,font={\scshape},#1]
      \int_step_inline:nnnn {1}{2} {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq} {
      \item[\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1}]  \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {##1+1}
      }
    \end{itemize}
  }
 \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\speciallist{Foo,bar,foobar,barfoo}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So one of the entries has a comma in it. It there anything I can do to 'escape' the comma?

Comment: @AmleshSivanantham: Use a `{}` pair, i.e. `{foo,foobar}, otherstuff`

Comment: Cheers my friend!!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with `pgfplotstable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14} 

\pgfplotstableset{
    col sep=comma,
    string type,
    header=false,
    every head row/.style={output empty row},
    columns={[index]0,[index]1},
    every col no 0/.style={string type, column type={>{\scshape}r}},
    every col no 1/.style={string type,column type=l}
    }


\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{
        Foo,bar
        foobar,barfoo   
        }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1)! i think that you can omit `\arraybackslash` in definition for `every col no 0/.style`.